# gconf-editor settings not being saved

Tags: 11.04, gconf

Recent gconf-editor settings

In terminal

```
gconftool-2 --type int --set /desktop/gnome/thumbnail_cache/maximum_age "-1"
```

Cannot make setting stick. I can change the setting if the integer is a positive number but it will not resort to MINUS number

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu / Pinguy 11.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu; other distributions are offtopic here, try our friends at the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What do you mean by "other" distrubutions when Pinguy is based on Ubuntu. It is not offtopic because it effects both distros or any distros using Ubuntu as a base. To clarify ie: no questions should be asked here if it doesn't pertain to Ubuntu directly? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Rick - correct, whilst a distro such as pinguy is theoretically based on ubuntu, we as a ubuntu community (or at least the majority anyway) do not have the indepth knowledge as to what the pinguy maintainers may have changed.  This sort of question should be asked on the pinguy forums (I'm assuming there is one somewhere).

Comment: That's not good but I suppose you have to draw the boundaries some place.

Comment: this  gconftool question is quite likely independent of distribution, in any event answer below is what's needed on Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little tricky setting negative values with  gconftool, you need to prepend with `--`

So for your example

```
gconftool --set --type int  /desktop/gnome/thumbnail_cache/maximum_age -- -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope this might still not work. I suggest you to Download Dconf. Its the newer version of Gconf. See I dont know much about these. But few days back when my login sound was not working I frist tried to reset a sound value using Gconf but after logout the value were lost. After that I tried Dconf and It worked !!!

I think Gconf is for old apps and Dconf is for newer One.